# general protection error on linux based OS

Tags: linux, interrupt

I am getting a General protection error while I run a binary. But there is no core dump. How do I debug the problem ?

Is this the problem with the "ld" i am using ?

> kernel: testbin[24879] general protection ip:7fd7271585e0 sp:7fff1ef55070 error:0 in ld-2.14.so[7fd727142000+20000]

Answer (score 1):

Before debugging, re-compile your program with debugging symbols (`-g` option), else you wont have enough detail information to effectively and quickly debug it (like filename, function, line).

There are more programs for debugging programs but for now I will suggest you valgrind.

So run your program through valgrind:

```
valgrind /path/to/your/program
```

and then reproduce steps to cause your program to [General Protection Fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_protection_fault#Technical_causes_for_faults).

---

If the software isnt yours, you'll have to contact the author and get support.